# How to calculate a number of all possible random walks without self-intersections?

Tags: combinatorics, random-walk

Is there a certain formula, that gives number of all possible non-self-intersected `N` walks?

`N` is number of steps of the walk. Grid is endless, size doesn't matter.

Random walks in the rectangle grid.
[image]

Superposition of all possible self-avoiding walks for N=3(each begin from same point)
[image]

First I thought, it should be something like $P=P_{prev}+(P_{prev}*3)$(P - number of possible walks), but it's wrong, because number of possible walks for `N=3` is 28 but not 64

Comment: What kind of random walks do you mean?

Comment: @user, edited question

Comment: Do you mean all the self-avoiding random walks on a square lattice of length at most N? You can find information on that problem for lengths exactly N at https://oeis.org/A001411, and then add them up.

Comment: @C.Martin, hmm, I've been counting wrong, but now I get 28 walks for N=3, but 100% not 12

Comment: It starts at $1$ for  $0$ steps, so $12$ is for two step walks and $36$ is for $3$ step walks.  For any of the $12$ two step walks you still cannot intersect on the third step so there are $36$.  For four steps there are only eight that self-intersect.  You can go four directions on the first step, turn either of two directions on the second, and complete the square.  If we didn't care about intersection there would be $3 \cdot 36=108$ so subtracting the $8$ we are left with $100$ that do not self-intersect.

Comment: @RossMillikan, I understood where I lost 8 steps, thank You too.